# Vaadin Flow Treegrid - empty rows after expand

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, treegrid

I use a TreeGrid in Vaadin 19.0.6 and add items like this:

```
final TreeData<BEAN> treeData = dataProvider.getTreeData();
treeData.addItems(items, getChildren::apply);
```

When I select a root-node which contains children and after that expand this root node, the children are expanded but the other root nodes disappear.

[image: treegrid]

If I collapse/expand this node several times, the items are back again.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks for help!
Daniel

Comment: It's maybe a bit hard to tell, whether your screenshot has those items just scrolled away (`overflow: hidden`). Can you rule out, that this is isn't just a visual problem (e.g. checking the DOM). Could you also please add how equals and hashCode are defined and how your "parent-child" relation is defined for `BEAN`.

Comment: what is your implementation of getChildren?